# Fetch JSONFile Reponse in angular

Tags: json, angular

I have one json file which contains multiple objects inside another object,I want to iterate there key and values in my HTML Page:
Exemple :

```
{
    "firstName": "Ayoub",
    "lastName": "Gammar",
    "mntDc": 502.0,
    "childs": [
        {
            "firstName": "Rafik",
            "lastName": "Mansour",
            "mntDc": 500.0,
            "username": "user3"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Ahmed",
            "lastName": "Makni",
            "mntDc": 1.0,
            "childs": [
                {
                    "firstName": "ALi",
                    "lastName": "hama",
                    "mntDc": 500.0,
                    "username": "admin"
                }
            ],
            "username": "user2"
        }
    ],
    "username": "user1"
}
```

Angular Methode :

````
    this.usrerArbre.getArbre().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log('data'+data);
      this.arbreUSer=data;;
    },error1 => {
      console.log(error1)
    })
  }```
````

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i need to fetch  All this Object Object one by one in HMTL File

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand which key you want to iterate. If you want to iterate the `childs` key then you can iterate it like this:

```
(data.childs||[]).forEach((item, index) {
  console.log(item, index);
});
```

But if you want to iterate the whole object then you can get its keys from:

```
let keys = Object.keys(data);
(keys||[]).forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(data[item], index); // You will get the each object key value here
});
```

Comment: Error : the property childs does not existe in Object

Comment: try the second one what you will get in the console?

Comment: the second one work but give me juste the last object :ALi
                   hama
                    500.0
                    admin

Comment: Can you share the ouput?

Comment: ALi 0
rtl.component.ts:31 hama 1
rtl.component.ts:31 500 2
rtl.component.ts:31 []length: 0__proto__: Array(0) 3
rtl.component.ts:31 admin 4

Comment: in my case i need to fetch all object and thier  childs

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
this.usrerArbre.getArbre().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log('data'+data);
      this.arbreUSer=data.childs;
    },error1 => {
      console.log(error1)
    })
  }
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let data of arbreUSer">
<p>{{data.firstName}}</p>
<p>{{data.lastName}}</p>
<p>{{data.mntDc}}</p>
<p>{{data.userName}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i have this error : the property childs does not existe in Object

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution:

```
var result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({key,value}));
//console.log(result);
```